# How do I create a multiline text file with Echo in Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, echo, textfiles

I'm using Windows 7 and I would like to quickly create a small text file with a few lines of text in the Command prompt.

I can create a single line text file with:

```
echo hello > myfile.txt
```

but how can I create a text file with multiple lines using this echo command? I have tried with the following, which doesn't work when I read the file with `more`:

```
echo hello\nsecond line > myfile.txt
```

Any suggestions? Or is there any other standard command that I can use for this instead of `echo`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use the >> characters to append a second line to the file, e.g.

```
echo hello > myfile.txt
echo second line >> myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 22):

There are three ways.

1. Append each line using `>>`:

   ```
   C:\Users\Elias>echo foo > a.txt
   C:\Users\Elias>echo bar >> a.txt
   ```
2. Use parentheses to echo multiple lines:

   ```
   C:\Users\Elias>(echo foo
   More? echo bar) > a.txt
   ```
3. Type caret (`^`) and hit ENTER twice after each line to continue adding lines:

   ```
   C:\Users\Elias>echo foo^
   More?
   More? bar > a.txt
   ```

All the above produce the same file:

```
C:\Users\Elias>type a.txt
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 2):

If you REALLY want to type everything in a single line you can just put an `&` for each new line, like:

```
echo hello >> myfile.txt & echo second line >> myfile.txt
```

but efotinis' answer is the easiest one.

Answer (score -2):

You can put a space between each line to write:

```
echo line1 line2 "line 3" > file.txt
```

Comment: This displays everything in one line:
`line1 line2 "line 3"`

Comment: This works in powershell, not command prompt.